# Get/Append Attribute with JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on an input slider function. I have it successfully working with jQuery, but I want to do it with pure JS.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PbED3/ . Code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/78bouskgb/tumblr_n381qg_QRTS1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" />    
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" onchange="rangevalue.value=value" value="100"/>
  <output id="rangevalue">100</output>
</div>
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$(function() {

$("#slider").change(function(e) {   
        $(".image").css("height", $(this).val() * 2 + "px");    
    });

});
```

As you an see, the function gets the input value from the slider and appends it to the image element as a CSS height value.

I want to do this without Jquery.

So far my function is this:

```
//Pure JS
var value = document.getElementById("#slider").value;
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('.image');

image.style.height= value + "px";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how it would work, the HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/78bouskgb/tumblr_n381qg_QRTS1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" />    
</div>

<div class="slider">
    <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="100"/>
    <output id="rangevalue">100</output>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var rangevalue = document.getElementById("rangevalue");
var image = document.querySelector('.image');

slider.onchange = function () {
    image.style.height = (slider.value * 2) + 'px';
    rangevalue.value = slider.value;
};
```

The thing with your code is that you are using CSS selector terminology with `document.getElementById`, which just needs the id of the element. If you want to use CSS selectors as you do with jQuery then use `document.querySelector` (grabs the first element that corresponds to the selector) or `document.querySelectorAll`. And also, you needed to place your callback inside an `onchange` event handler of the slider element.

Answer (score 0):

You were getting there, here is a working example without jQuery:

```
var slider =  document.getElementById("slider");

if (slider.addEventListener) {
    slider.addEventListener("change", slideHandler, false);
} else {
    slider.attachEvent('onchange', slideHandler);
}  

function slideHandler() {
    var value = slider.value;
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0];
    if (image) {
        image.style.height= value + "px";
    }
}
```

Main issues were than you needed to bind the event (`addEventListener` or `attachEvent`) and you were still passing jQuery style selectors to the `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` functions. Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you only want to update the first instance found.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbED3/4/)

Comment: Could you not use a combination of mouseMove and mouseDown for a more fluid appearance

Comment: It's unlikely that a browser that doesn't support *addEventListener* will support *getElementsByClassName*, but I'm willing to be surprised about that. :-)